# Activities and notification

Tags: android

In my app I've few activities and a notification that starts everyday. If I've an activity opened and my app to background, when I click on notification (that starts a new activity) I see old activity and no activity of notification. How I can resolve?

Comment: can we see some code? Especially where you initialize the notification?